# make dynamically generated href call a c# function

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, htmlgenericcontrol

I am trying to build a dropdown as below.

[image: this is the menu that I need to generate]

I am generating html ul & li tags as below and works fine. However, everytime there is an anch tag (see the in-line comment); I need to be able to call a function and pass a text that was clicked. How can I do this?

```
        foreach (var productType in productTypesNames.Keys)
        {
            var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            nav.Controls.Add(li);
            var ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

            var anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");

            foreach (var pName in productTypesNames[productType] )
            {
                var subLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                var anch = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                anch.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
                //**THIS NEEDS TO CALL A C# FUNCTION AND PASS pName; instead of #**
                anch.InnerHtml = pName;
                subLi.Controls.Add(anch);
                ul.Controls.Add(subLi);
            }
            anchor.InnerHtml = productType;
            li.Controls.Add(anchor);
            li.Controls.Add(ul);
        }
```

Comment: You _do_ know that the markup lives in the browser, and the C# code lives in the server?

Comment: I know it's jQuery oriented, but this article explans well the difference between client and server and the HTTP protocol that sits in the middle: http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/02/beginning-with-jquery-solid-foundation_22.html

Comment: Yes I do. Apologies for not being clear :-(. But basically, I need to send a text that was clicked to another server-side function for further processing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a postback, or want it, use a `LinkButton` control, easily built dynamically instead of your `HtmlGenericControl("a")`, and have the server-side onclick method call your other method.

Otherwise you need AJAX as others have explained.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `href` execute a JS function and that can call the server via AJAX. You can had code your own, or use jQuery or `[WebMethod]`s with ASP.NET Ajax.

The idea is that you can execute a server-side method by calling the server via Ajax.

Also, look at the way JSONP works - maybe you can "ping" another page with URL parameters of your choosing to do a one-way async call.